# Correlation: "If correlation between A and B is +0.4 and that of B and C is also +0.4 then correlation of A and C cannot be +0.4"?

Tags: statistics, correlation

In financial course today, we were using Harry Markovitz Portfolio Selection Theory.
During that , the professor said the following statement
"If correlation between A and B is +0.4 and that of B and C is also +0.4 then correlation of A and C cannot be +0.4"

So to prove that his statement is invalid. I came up with following example

(Example starts)
Say there are 3 sets of data for X, Y and Z

```
X   Y   Z
1   5   10
2   10  20
4   20  40
8   40  80
16  80  160
32  160 320
```

The correlation between:

```
1. X and Y is 1
2. Y and Z is 1
3. X and Z is 1
```

(Example ends)

However, this is only 1 example. I cannot come up with other data sets that would yield all 3 coefficients to be equal.

So I would like to know whether the statement as given by the professor is valid or not? If not then how should I go about proving that it is invalid aside from the example above.

Comment: It's easy to come up with examples with $\rho=1$...just let $A=B=C$.  As to this...well, the transitivity properties of correlation are very weak.  See [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122888/how-to-infer-correlations-from-correlations) for instance.  Using the bounds there all I see is that $  .16-.84 ≤\rho_{AC}≤.16+.84$ which isn't terribly useful.  Certainly, $.4$ is well within that range.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen  Well, you do get a non-trivial lower bound of $-.68$.  But, the point is that this is the range, not an estimate of it.  Everything in that range is achievable.

Comment: @lulu yes you’re right, was confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your professor is certainly wrong. Any valid correlation matrix (where “valid” means positive definite, symmetric, and having ones on the main diagonal) can be the correlation structure of some random variables... just take a multivariate normal with that covariance matrix. It should be easy to check that the $3\times 3$ matrix with ones on the main diagonal and $0.4$ for all off diagonal elements is positive definite.

In fact, it’s a fairly common modeling choice to assume a set of variables all have the same pairwise correlation. It will work for any positive correlation, but there is a limit to how much the negative pairwise correlation can be (above that limit the matrix will cease to be positive definite).